# Frame is not showing Properly using swing

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

I have a frame. Title is the Setting .Here is the code :

```
    setTitle("Setting");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
```

Here i am not able to show frame properly.Can You Please Suggest me.Here if i expand from corner ,it is showing.Please Help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you add components to frame you need to call

```
pack();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you set bounds of the frame?

```
setBounds(positionX, positionY, width, height);
```

Comment: No i didnt set anything

Comment: You have to do it or the frame won't know his own size. Also you can call `pack`and it will set the size as it needs.